# VM:foundation memory leak in iPhone 4s(iOS7)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

When I run a HDR camera app on iphone 4s (iOS7), the Xcode profiler shows a "VM:foundation" memory leak which gets accumulated with capturing images. It is not happening in case of iOS6 devices. What is VM foundation error? How to manage the VM leaks? Here I am capturing yuv frames from camera and processing them to get the necessary information for HDR creation. With each capture the VM: foundation value is getting increased by around 10mb for iphone4s and 2 mb for ipad2 which is consistent with their respective camera quality.

Comment: Having a similar problem, where `Foundation` isn't deallocating.